# jQuery to set div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the function below it allows me to set the divs to the max height using the specific class however I need to adjust it to allow me to set the height of each row dynamically.

**Example:**

The `menuBoxesParagraph` boxes within `row` could be a different height then the boxes within `rowX` I need to be able to get the `max` `.menuBoxesParagraph` height for each **"row"** and then be able to set the row height based on whatever the `max` is - I might have a .menuBoxesParagraph box that is 298px high - this would then be the highest box within that specific row - the row height should then be that height

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph">
        <p>Content Row</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rowX">
    <div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph">
        <p>Content Row X</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current jQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var max = -1;
    $('.menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).height(); 
    max = h > max ? h : max;   
    });
    $(".menuBoxesParagraph").css("height",max+"px");

    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.menuBoxesParagraph{
    width: 25%;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    margin: 2% 1% 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menuBoxesParagraph:before, .menuBoxesParagraph:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.menuBoxesParagraph:after { clear: both; }
.menuBoxesParagraph { zoom: 1; }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "setting height of each row dynamically", I actually did not get it

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi I might have a `.menuBoxesParagraph` box that is `298px` high - this would then be the highest box within that specific row - the row height should then be that hight

Comment: will you have more than 1 `.menuBoxesParagraph ` within each `row`? if you set `row` height to max  height of these it will not show all `menuBoxesParagraph` es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set `border` and `padding` CSS to `.menuBoxesParagraph` so to calculate it's actual height you should use `outerHeight()` function. and as I undrestand you want to have rows, that their height is set to maximum height of `.menuBoxesParagraph`  so for each `row` you should have this function called.like [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sh7aq4od/14/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max = -1;
    $('.row .menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
    max = h > max ? h : max;   
    });
    $(".row .menuBoxesParagraph").outerHeight(max+"px"); 
   $(".row").css("height",max+"px");

    var max1 = -1;
    $('.row1 .menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
    max1 = h > max1 ? h : max1;   
    });
    $(".row1 .menuBoxesParagraph").outerHeight(max1+"px"); 
    $(".row1").css("height",max1+"px");
    
    var max2 = -1;
    $('.row2 .menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
    max2 = h > max2 ? h : max2;   
    });
    $(".row2 .menuBoxesParagraph").outerHeight(max2+"px"); 
    $(".row2").css("height",max2+"px");
    
    var max3 = -1;
    $('.row3 .menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
    max3 = h > max3 ? h : max3;   
    });
    $(".row3 .menuBoxesParagraph").outerHeight(max3+"px"); 
    $(".row3").css("height",max3+"px");
});
```

Comment: Hey, Your getting close however its taking it from the parent like it should be however there is a div above what I have given and thats been classed as the parent and not my "row"

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rd1LHrBE6IL6nQhhpF1e?p=preview in this case,each row is getting max height of `.menuBoxesParagraph` inside it. is it whatyou want @JessMcKenzie?

Comment: I used 'outerHeight()` function to calculate the border and padding you add to `.menuBoxesParagraph` too

Comment: It doesnt seem to be applying the height to the paragraph - http://jsfiddle.net/sh7aq4od/

Comment: I really do not get what you want.in your jsfiddle `.row` height is set to `380px`. what is exactly you want? or why do you want to set heigh for row at all ? maybe if you tell me the reason I will get what you want

Comment: Here is a row - the biggest is "dips and bits" I need the row to be that height - https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxpd4u8ae3dlv3g/Screenshot%202015-08-31%2018.35.24.png?dl=0 every row is diff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88342/discussion-between-shirin-abdolahi-and-jess-mckenzie).

Answer (score 0):

you just replace:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var max = -1;
    $('.menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
        var h = $(this).outerHeight(); 
        max = h > max ? h : max;   

        $(this).css("height",max+"px");
   });
});
```

Comment: Still not correct -  I might have a .menuBoxesParagraph box that is 298px high - this would then be the highest box within that specific row - the row height should then be that hight

Comment: Hi, did you fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to make just changes in your script coz you need to apply the height to the each row and you have put the css applying code out side of the scope where actually the you get the DOM element of each row here i have given the example demo code

> **and another thing is that you must wrap the ternary conditions in**
>   **brackets that will check for the comparisons of the value**

here is the change you need to get

check out

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var max = -1;
    $('.menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
     var h = $(this).outerHeight();       
     max = (h > max) ? h : max;   
        $(".menuBoxesParagraph").css("height",max+"px");
    });
 });
```

here is the demo working code

[DEmO](https://jsfiddle.net/nc3a7zkc/5/)

---

**Updated answer**

I tried to apply height to two different div's and here is the result of your expectation

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var tmpMax = -1;    
    $('.menuBoxesParagraph').each(function() {
        debugger;
        if($(this).height()>tmpMax){
   tmpMax =  $(this).height(); 
        }                                      
    });
    $(".menuBoxesParagraph").css("height",tmpMax+"px");    
 });
```

```css
.menuBoxesParagraph{
    width: 25%;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    margin: 2% 1% 0px 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.menuBoxesParagraph:before, .menuBoxesParagraph:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.menuBoxesParagraph:after { clear: both; }
.menuBoxesParagraph { zoom: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph" style="height:100px;">
        <p>Content Row</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rowX">
    <div class="menu1 menuBoxesParagraph" style="height:300px;">
        <p>Content Row X</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the updated DEMO [UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nc3a7zkc/19/)

Comment: @Jess McKenzie please check out the answer

Comment: I have but I tried in the demo to add more content and it adjusted both boxes.  Nowhere is the "row" being taken into account: - I might have a .menuBoxesParagraph box that is 298px high - this would then be the highest box within that specific row - the row height should then be that height

Comment: @JessMcKenzie which element do you want to apply height i just applied what you have only given so can you let me clear first .?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to make boxes of each row of equal height individually, correct? If so then this code will do the thing.

All you needed to do is group each row boxes separately and then apply the height logic.

```
var rowsArr=[]
var boxesArr=[]
var prevParent;
allBoxes=$('.menuBoxesParagraph')
allBoxes.each(function(i) {
    if(prevParent && prevParent[0]!=$(this).parent()[0]){
        rowsArr.push(boxesArr.slice())
        boxesArr=[]
    }
    boxesArr.push($(this)[0]);
    prevParent=$(this).parent();
    if(i==allBoxes.length-1){
        rowsArr.push(boxesArr.slice())
    }
});

for(i=0;i<=rowsArr.length;i++){
    thisBoxes=$(rowsArr[i])
    var max = -1;
    thisBoxes.each(function() {
        var h = $(this).height(); 
        max = h > max ? h : max;   
    });
    thisBoxes.css("height",max+"px");
}
```